# proofing pyramid volume formula using integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm studying the proof of pyramid volume formula using integration. In the video minute [12:10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56_QS7g4FHk) when the professor already got the $S$ variable which is the side of the pyramid base he continues to do an integration which is this one: $$ \int_0^h{\left[a(1-\frac{1}{h}y)\right]^2 dy} $$ and in a translation box he writes like this which I do not understand why the derivative of the $$1-\frac{1}{h}y$$ becomes $-\frac{1}{h}$ ??? :

$$u = 1-\frac{1}{h}y $$
$$du = -\frac{1}{h}dy $$

the substitution rule for the definite integral require the $du = g'(x) dx$ in this case it can be $du = g'(y) dy$ but in this case it is not equal to $-\frac{1}{h}dy$

please have a look at the video only via browser in the computer, if you use youtube app on mobile device you will not see the same result.

I'm newbie please give me step by step and detailed explanation answer. Thank you ^^

Comment: Note that $h$ here is a **constant**. So this is just a simple derivative of the form: $u=a+by \implies du/dy = b$